# How add JQuery code in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a mouse effect with a gif file and I found the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>      
$(function(){
    $("body").mousemove(
        function(e){
            $("<img src='http://www.favicon.cc/logo3d/618187.png' />")
            .css({
                'position':'absolute', 
                'top':e.pageY+5,
                'left':e.pageX+-15,
                'width':'30px',
                'height':'30px'
            }).prependTo( $(document.body))
            .fadeOut(100, 'linear', function(){
                $(this).remove(); 
            });
        });
});
</script>
</body>
```

When I ran the html file I cannot see anything, for it, I think I am making a mistake in the code, Could anybody help me to fix?

Comment: works fine on mine [chromium] (obviously there's nothing in it, but there are stars when you the mouse). did you change anything on that code?

Comment: your HTML code posted here is wrong, you forget some closing tags

Comment: It's working here with `html` instead of `body`: http://jsfiddle.net/fNZeX/

Comment: You are closing head tag with a body tag?

Comment: You appear to be missing your opening `<body>` tag, and your closing `</head>`.

Comment: First, thanks for your help ! On the other hand Could you say me the right code, please....

Comment: Are you using a proper webserver (e.g., the Apache distribution in XAMPP, or similar)? I believe it won't work if you simply double-click the html file.

Comment: Hi all, it works fine with Explorer and Chrome but it is not working with Firefox Do you know what is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Attach the mouse listener to `$(document)` instead of `$('body')`.

Also in your code you are missing your closing `</head>` and start `<body>` tag (that you were using in the selector).

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeb7d/)**

Comment: @AlejandroCastan, I updated the answer. If it was useful please click to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

While you have few errors in the code, it works fine.

The reason you don't see anything in firefox is that the body of the HTML is empty and the stars won't show up unless there's content.

It works fine on chromium and rekonq.

Just add content, and it will work fine

```
<html>
<head>
<script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>      
$(function(){
    $(function(){
$("html").mousemove(
    function(e){
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            $("<img src='http://www.favicon.cc/logo3d/618187.png' id='hover_" +i+"' />")
            .css({
                'position':'absolute', 
                'top':e.pageY+i*5,
                'left':e.pageX+i*10,
                'width':'30px',
                'height':'30px'
            }).prependTo( $(document.body))
            .fadeOut(100, 'linear', function(){
                $(this).remove(); 
            });
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Add content </h1>
<p> some content </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Test [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashC9/1/)

you can change the dimensions as you want. If you want you can create an array with the given dX and dY changes and use that to position the images.

or try this, Test [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashC9/4/)

Comment: Hi all,Thanks to all your answers ! It is works fine right now but I would need to add several images together in different places, for it, Could you how add more.png images to the code?

Comment: Hi xcoat, I tried your code and Firefox works fine right now but like I said I would need to add several png images together and in different places for it, Is it possible add any Array or something? Thanks

Comment: I would need to do some similar to this  dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex13/trailer.htm  but the one gif object should be in the center and the other gif objects around it. thanks

Comment: Yes I did, and always appears only an image

Comment: Hi xcorat, thanks again sorry for my ignorance but in your code appears several times the same image and I would need to add different images and a little more big that this. Would it be possible? Best Regards

Comment: if you look at the code in http://jsfiddle.net/ashC9/4/, you should be able to figure out what you need to add to have different images. Try it, and PM me if u have questions